Stationary temperature relationships from non-stationary data?
In stable operating conditions, the temperature $T$ of an engine can be thought as a monotone increasing function of its angular speed $\omega$. However, if $\omega$ changes abruptly, the temperature takes time to adjust and reach a new steady value.
We have a dataset where each data point is a pair ($\omega_i$, $T_i$) representing the simultaneously measured angular speed and temperature at a specific known times. These measurements were recorded under non-stationary conditions.
How can I use the dataset to predict numerically the value of $T$, for a given $\omega$, for stationary conditions?
